# How to get same result in C or C++ same as toLowerCase in Java or string.lower() in Python?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need a C or C++ function(or library) which works like `String.toLowerCase()` in Java.

I know that I can use `tolower()` for English, but what I need is a function (or library) can cover global language. (Actually, It needs to cover 9 languages listed below.)

## language list

```
Dutch
English
French
German
Italian
Portuguese
Russian
Spanish
Ukrainian
```

Add, These characters in the first line below are Input and the second line is expected result

LINE 1:

```
AÁÀÂÄĂĀÃÅÆBCĆČÇDEÉÈÊËĚĘFGHℏIÍÌÎÏJKLŁMNŃŇÑOÓÒÔÖÕØŒPQRŘSŚŠŞTŢUÚÙÛÜŪVWXYÝZŹŽΑΔΕΘΛΜΝΠΡΣΣΦΩАБВГҐДЕЁЄЖЗИЙІЇКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
```

LINE 2:

```
aáàâäăāãåæbcćčçdeéèêëěęfghℏiíìîïjklłmnńňñoóòôöõøœpqrřsśšştţuúùûüūvwxyýzźžαδεθλμνπρσςφωабвгґдеёєжзийіїклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
```

I verified results from Java `toLowerCase()` and Python `string.lower()`
and both are correct.

Is there any way to translate to lowercase letter in C or C++?

And **Important thing is that the letters are read from a file encoded 'UTF-8'!**

Please help me. My English is not very good, so please use simple English as much as you can.

Comment: This question is amazing. Just what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find what you need in the Boost libraries - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html

Quoting from their website:

> Boost.Locale gives powerful tools for development of cross platform
>   localized software - the software that talks to user in its language.
>
> Provided Features:
>
> ```
> Correct case conversion, case folding and normalization.
> Collation (sorting), including support for 4 Unicode collation levels.
> ....
> ```

You get the idea, I hope. The function you need is

```
Boost::Locale::to_lower(yourUTF8String)
```

Comment: oh oh. java to lowecase converts char not string.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan Not sure what you are saying... a function “which works LIKE Java...” but operates on C objects (because it’s a C function that is asked for). Yes maybe you need a char* array rather than a string object - do you think that is something a reader of this question could not figure out?

Comment: Sorry my bad... slightly. The person asked about Java´s  Character.toLowerCase to be specific. Which doest convert a string to lowercase, but a character to lowercase. But further reading showed he actually meant string to lowercase. However HELP ME OUT. Are the cpp unicode functions such as std::towupper worth there grain of salt. cpp version takes a 16bit char as input, but java version takes a 32bit int as input!

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan I can’t answer that, sorry. “It depends”, I suppose...

Comment: I experiemented a little and it seems it doesnt work for characters outside of ascii

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan that seems disappointing. 16 bit is enough for UTF-16, ie “most of Unicode”. Hard to imagine they would only use the bottom byte...

Comment: I saw the russion letters print out the same for towlower and towupper